# Convert TFSBuild.proj to MSBuild script

Tags: tfs, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a way to convert a TFSBuild.proj file into a simple MSBuild without the TFS stuff? Our teams are wanting to move away from TFS in favor of a git/jenkin approach and I'm trying to see if there is an easy way to convert the tfs scripts. I know that the TFSBuild.proj is built on top of MSBuild and I can actually call msbuild TFSBuild.proj to get it to work. My issue is that our new ci server will not have tfs on it so I'll get errors like this:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Thoughts? I'm guessing I'm probably just going to have to manually convert these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert TFSBuild.proj into simple MSBuild, because it already is. When you queue a build in TFS the Build Agent is just doing "msbuild.exe TFSBuild.proj". Maybe with some additional parameters (defined in the Build Definition) and of course preparing the folders before.

The easiest solution to your problem is to install a Visual Studio on the server, this will bring all the requirements for builds, like MSBuild, frameworks and SDKs.